# Bootstrap slider, how to snap to just points

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-slider

How do I get this slider to snap to the points only: 
https://jsbin.com/hepiyawumi/edit?html,output

I have tried using `data-slider-step` but as the points have values that are not evenly apart, I do not get the desired result.

Desired result is to snap to 0, 5, 10, 20, 30 only, and nowhere in between.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this:

1. Remove `data-slider-step="5"`
2. Change `data-slider-ticks="[0, 5, 10, 20, 30]"` to `data-slider-ticks="[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]"`
3. Use the `formatter` option to get the tooltip to say the same thing as the tick labels